# C# - Verificar se está faltando datas no periodo selecionado

Tags: c#, pl-sql, psql

Eu tenho a seguinte *SQL*

```
SELECT 
    dt_finished::date AS "DataFinalizacao",
    count(DISTINCT tba.id_batches) AS "Quantidade Total"
FROM tb_batches AS tba
INNER JOIN tb_routes tro ON (tro.fk_id_products = tba.fk_id_products 
    AND tro.fk_id_sessions = 70 
    AND tba.finished = TRUE)
WHERE tba.dt_finished::date <= now()::date 
    AND tba.dt_finished::date >= (now() - INTERVAL '15 day')::date
GROUP BY tba.dt_finished::date
ORDER BY tba.dt_finished::date DESC
```

Eu preciso retornar todos os dias que tiveram `batch` finalizado, se não houver `batch` finalizado naquele dia devera trazer o dia só que com a quantidade total zerada.
O problema é que ele não está trazendo a data.

Como tratar isso no C# ou na *SQL*?

[image: printscreen com a resultset de uma consulta]

Minha classe

```
public class TaxaProducaoBLL : ITaxaProducaoBLL
    {
        public IEnumerable<TaxaProducaoOV> CalcularTaxaProducao(IEnumerable<TaxaProducaoOV> taxaProducao)
        {
            foreach (var taxa in taxaProducao)
            {

            }
            return new List<TaxaProducaoOV>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade você tem que usar `LEFT JOIN`, que aí você traz os resultados independente se possui relação com a `tb_routes` e o `COUNT()` vai lhe retornar 0.

O `INNER JOIN` você diz que quer pegar tudo da `tb_batches` que esteja na `tb_routes`

Comment: O esquema e que o seguinte, nao há nada salvo essa data que falta no banco, eu tenho que verificar no periodo das datas do select se há datas faltando , e colocar essas datas ... nao sei se deu pra entender bem...

Comment: ah entendi, isso é mais complexo você teria que ter uma tabela auxiliar de datas, para a primeira consulta ser nela então. dessa maneira ele só pega os registros que existam na tabela

Comment: Entendi, acho q utilizando uma tabela auxiliar seria melhor msm :D